# contact module drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-contact-form

I just installed the contact module for drupal 7 and set all permissions like the documentation said. I am not seeing a link in the main menu. How do I enable it/access it? This isn't clear to me. Does anyone have experience with it?

Answer (score 3):

I think the contact link is in the Navigation menu and disabled by default. Go to `admin/structure/menus`, into the `Navigation` menu, enable the contact link and save.

Comment: Is there no way too add it no a basic page in the main menu?